# How can I add Progressbar in downloading functionality in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, progress-bar

I am downloading PDF from server and store it into local storage.
Now When I open screen at that time it stream from URL and shows CircularProgressIndicator.
But when I tap on download that time I want to make loading Widget where I can show download progress.
And this 2 progressbar needs to be worked separately.
How can I achieve that?

```
body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 10,
              child: _isLoading   // This is for locading from URL
                  ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                  : PDFViewer(document: doc),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

This is How I download PDF from url and store into local storage.

```
await dio.download(
        widget.urlName,
        pathBookForDB,
        onReceiveProgress: (count, total) => {
          setState(() {
            valDownload = ((count / total) * 100).toString();
          })
        },
      );
```

Comment: `CircularProgressIndicator` has `value` property, the range is [0..1] which indicates the progress

Comment: I have to use 2 progressbars. One which I showed you is for loading from url. Now I have function to download. that time I need to show progressbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flutter pub [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator)

Include the below code in body.

```
LinearPercentIndicator(
    width: 140.0,
    lineHeight: 14.0,
    percent: 0.5,
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    progressColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
```

For your code you can go like below.

```
  _isLoading // This is for locading from URL
      ? Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: new LinearPercentIndicator(
        width: 170.0,
        animation: true,
        animationDuration: 1000,
        lineHeight: 20.0,
        leading: new Text("left content"),
        trailing: new Text("right content"),
        percent: 0.99,
        center: Text("99.0%"),
        linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.butt,
        progressColor: Colors.red,
       ),
     )
       : Container(),
```

Comment: But I have to use loader as a widget in my body section

Comment: you can use it as a widget

Comment: When I add in my body section it gives full black screen and crashes the app.

Comment: After successful download my screen got black.